# How do retrieve the MAC address of an access point using flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any method/way of retrieving the MAC address of the access point the device is connected to, using the flutter SDK?

Comment: Wifi/AP is a medium, it does not have its own interface: treat it as an ethernet cable.